# use of stateParam in ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I want to update same view depending on button clicked how to use stateParam and get id in controller.My app.js is as follows

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$stateParams){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page1');

   $stateProvider.state('page1', {
      url: "/page1",
      templateUrl: 'templates/page1.html',
     controller:'dataCtrl'
    })
      .state('page2', {
        url: "/page2",
        templateUrl: 'templates/page2.html',
        controller:'transCtrl'

      })

  })
```

my contoller is

```
angular.module('starter').controller('dataCtrl',function($scope,$state,$stateParams)
{
alert("gfb")
$scope.Jan= function (id) {
  alert("inside Jan");
  $state.go('page2',{id:id});
}
```

});

Answer (score 2):

Add the param in state like so:

```
.state('page2', {
        url: "/page2/:id",
        templateUrl: 'templates/page2.html',
        controller:'transCtrl'
      })
```

In transCtrl:

```
angular.module('starter').controller('transCtrl',function($scope,$state,$stateParams) {
var id = $stateParams.id;
}
```